# ros2-foxy-angles from_degrees Python example?

Tags: ros, ros2, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS nub

I found https://index.ros.org/p/angles/ and ros2-foxy-angles got installed by rosdep from my package.xml:

```
  <exec_depend>angles</exec_depend>
```

The git says it hasn't changed but there are no foxy "API Docs" and the ROS1 docs only show C++.

Where can I find a Python example for what to import?

```
# get degrees to radians func
from ??? import from_degrees

        self.msg_field_of_view = from_degrees(25.0)     # +/- 12.5 degree FOV (~60cm at max range)
```

I'm starting to think Foxy does not support angles in Python.  (the ROS2 setup.py refers to catkin )
My temp workaround since I only need the degrees to radians func at the moment:

```
# get degrees to radians func
from math import radians

        self.msg_field_of_view = radians(25.0)     # +/- 12.5 degree FOV (~60cm at max range)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382391/ros2-foxy-angles-from_degrees-python-example?/) by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2021-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-14**:
If all else fails, it's easiest to look at [the source code](https://github.com/ros/angles/blob/fe974f2d84b719d3aa0593a4bf633183d75ba213/angles/src/angles/__init__.py).

Given that `angles` isn't really that complex (it's essentially a single file) and all functions are pretty well documented, that should provide you with the information you're looking for.

**Comment by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on 2021-07-14**:
Thank you for responding, but nowhere in the source code does anything tell me where ROS2 installs the source code.

Case in point: looking at the [source for std_msgs.msg.Float32](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/master/std_msgs/msg/Float32.msg) nowhere does it say to:

- place <exec_depends>std_msgs</exec_depends> in package.xml
- run rosdep install -i --from-path src in your ros2 workspace root
- place "from std_msgs.msg import Float32" in your Python program
  and life will be great, but I figured that out from the source code **AND** the similarity to the ROS2 pub/sub tutorial which publishes a "String" by "from std_msgs.msg import String"

[ROS2 angles python setup code](https://github.com/ros/angles/blob/ros2/angles/setup.py)seems to indicate the Python package is "angles", and suggest "from angles import from_degrees" **BUT**

- build succeeds
- execution says:

  from angles import from_degrees
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'angles'

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-14**:\

> but nowhere in the source code does anything tell me where ROS2 installs the source code.

Not the specific link I referred you to, no.

But [angles/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros/angles/blob/b7f12577bc7f6df49c816a98afef3f67574b8a09/angles/CMakeLists.txt) does. And so does [angles/setup.py](https://github.com/ros/angles/blob/b7f12577bc7f6df49c816a98afef3f67574b8a09/angles/setup.py), but that's indeed pre-ROS 2.

But in any case: I did not point you "the source code" to figure out where things are installed. I understood your question as asking "what functionality is offered by this package?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking in this case. From your question it appeared you were wondering how to *use* the `angles` package, once you've installed it (you wrote "ros2-foxy-angles got installed by rosdep from my package.xml").

I don't understand how `std_msgs.msg.Float32` is related.

The link to the source repository is displayed on the ROS Index page you already linked. See #q381559.

> but nowhere in the source code does anything tell me where ROS2 installs the source code.  [..] I'm starting to think Foxy does not support angles in Python.

While there is nothing in the package itself (ie: the actual business code) that would make it impossible to use this package on ROS 2, it does currently not install the Python-side. The `setup.py` is indeed pre-ament (meaning: `catkin`).

The `angles` package installed by `rosdep` for you is the C++ side.

If you have a need to use functionality *right* now, you could copy the relevant function(s) from the `__init__.py` and use them like that.

It would be nicer however if the Python side could be included in the next release.

I would recommend you open an issue on [the tracker](https://github.com/ros/angles/issues) to discuss what would be needed to get it released. I would expect it would only take an update of the `setup.py` and perhaps the `CMakeLists.txt`.

It could also be the maintainers would like to split the Python and C++ versions of the packages. That would require slightly more changes, but would still not be too much work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on 2021-07-14**:
Thank you for looking deeper into my original question: "Where can I find a Python example for what to import? (after installing ros2-angles-foxy)"

Indeed - the answer is "there is no example, and ros2 foxy does not support Python interface to angles"

As a ROS2 nub, tackling the port of ROS1 gopigo3_node to ROS2 seems to be exposing me to some ROS2 bleeding edges (migrating launch arguments documentation, and now Python angles not yet.)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-14**:\

> "Where can I find a Python example for what to import? (after installing ros2-angles-foxy)"

just to be extra clear: there would be nothing special about `angles` necessarily. It would just be another Python package. The fact it's used with ROS (1 or 2) does not really matter.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-14**:
And it seems you opened an issue on the tracker: [ros/angles#26](https://github.com/ros/angles/issues/26).